# Text isn't displayed in UITextView until loop is completed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, uitextview

I have a loop that iterates through an array of Products (products) to see if any of their ids (product_id) match that of a given product (p). The text of a UITextView (outputText) is updated to show the user how the search is progressing:

```
for (Product *q in products) {
    outputText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nChecking: %@", outputText.text, q.name];
    NSLog(@"%@\nChecking: %@", outputText.text, q.name);
    if ([q.product_id intValue] == [p.product_id intValue]) {
        outputText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nMatch: %@", outputText.text, q.name];
        break;
    }
}
```

The trouble is the UITextView doesn't seem to get updated until the loop is complete... The UITextView is blank for several seconds presumably while the loop is processed, although in the Xcode console i can see the nslog text scrolling along, and then all of a sudden the UITextView gets all the text in one go.

Is there any way to flush the text to the UITextView during the loop?

Any help much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are updating UI on the main thread
2. Call `[outputText setNeedsDisplay:YES];`

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply, I'm getting: No visible @interface for UITextView declares the selector 'setNeedsDisplay'